# C# MVC Route detection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to call customer profile page like "(www.mysite.com/John) or (www.mysite.com/customer name)"

so i had add route to be like that

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Profile",
              url: "{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );

 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but it always go to the first route as if i need to open any controller it does n`t work 
any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the action of customer name?

Comment: I just save the {id} in viewbag and work with it in JavaScript section the problem in any URl will go to this action (Home/Index/) even i call another controller

Comment: but can you show the action ? it would help to solve the problem

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string SurveyName = "";
            if (Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
                SurveyName = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SurveyName))
            {
                ViewBag.Survey = SurveyName;
            }
            return View();
        }

Comment: It's a pure route problem and can be solved with route constraint to restrict when it have to be reached. See my answer below.

Comment: and if you do `www.mysite.com/controller/action` in still goes to `home/index` ?

Comment: @DouglasGandini the route is working without any problem i think the OP has some confusion in understanding

Comment: yes if do www.mysite.com/controller/action it still goes to home/index

Comment: @amir can you show example of the url which is not working

Comment: when i try to do "www.mysite.com/John" it should go to "Home/index/{id}" and if i do "www.mysite.com/EmployeePage" which is "Employee/Index" it go to "Home/index/{id}" too and any other controller do the same

Comment: @amir oh now i understood the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the route wont work like that so you have two options

**1)** When going to any action your `URL` should be `www.mysite.com/controller/action` or else it will give `HTTP 404` error

**2)** You can make route unique by adding prefix `www.mysite.com/Customer/John` like this

```
  routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Profile",
     url: "Customer/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
     );
```

and your `action` should be

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    string SurveyName = "";
    if (id != null)
        SurveyName = id;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SurveyName))
    {
        ViewBag.Survey = SurveyName;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `controller` and `action` according to your requirement, you are still providing default values to `controller` and `action`.

You can also use `Html.ActionLink`at to refer to your desired view
ex. `Html.ActionLink("action_name","Controller_name")`

Answer (score 0):

Your route has a single optional parameter and is working like a catch all route.

**[EDIT]**
You can't use the constraint as I said on my previous answer if you don't have an pattern to restrict the route. Based on this you can remove the `id = UrlParameter.Optional` from defaults (by this change your route will be reached only when the url contains the id parameter).

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                      name: "Profile",
                      url: "{id}",
                      defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index"}
                     );
```

Another option is to create a [custom route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) to check if your profile id is valid but take care since it can slow down your application since it'll be executed on every request (maybe caching your profile list could help on this).

**[OLD ANSWER]**
An easy way to restrict a route scope is using constraint.

The route below is reached just if the id parameter is a value with 4 digits (you can use your own regex to fit your requirements).

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                      name: "Profile",
                      url: "{id}",
                      defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index"},
                      constraints: new { id = @"\d{4}" }
                     );
```

Comment: i had try this but it does n`t reach to "Home/Index" when i try "www.mysite.com/John". it give me 
The resource cannot be found.

Comment: You're right. I missed that your Id is a literal. See my edited answer.

Comment: it the same but i figure out that if i write full URL it will work like "www.mysite.come/Employee/Index" it will work good but if i write "www.mysite.com/Employee" it go to "home/index" thank you any way

Comment: It is exactly what you asked for. Your Profile route is pointing to Home/Index controller as in your initial post. Just change the controller and action names in your route definition to point to your Employee controller and it'll work as you expect (check out my edit).

Answer (score -1):

Make these changes. It worked for me.

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Profile",
              url: "{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "NewCon", action = "Demo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );

 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: it is the same as i did , any URl will redirect to "NewCon/Demo" but if you need to go to another controller it will also go to "NewCon/Demo"